# Serialize only those properties which are specified [XmlElement] without changing the original class

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

Code:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlElement("Company")]
    public string Company { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Amount")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public int companyid { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to serilize only thoese which are specified with `[XmlElement]`, companyid not to be serilized.

So, what can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377414/excluding-some-properties-during-serialization-without-changing-the-original-cla. Looks like one solution is to use `XmlAttributeOverrides`.

Comment: but in that there is [xmlignore] used , but as in my case , to serilize only those which are specified xmlelement, as i do not want to modify my orignal class.

Comment: Please see the update to my answer, the second code snippet. Hopefully that should work for you...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example I put together in LinqPad. The first 4 lines of the `Main` method set up an `XmlAttributeOverrides` instance that is then used to tell the `XmlSerializer` to not serialize the `companyid` property.

```
void Main()
{
    //Serialize, but ignore companyid
    var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
    var attributes = new XmlAttributes();
    attributes.XmlIgnore = true;
    overrides.Add(typeof(MyClass), "companyid", attributes);

    using(var sw = new StringWriter()) {
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass), overrides);
        var a = new MyClass() { 
                                       Company = "Company Name", 
                                       Amount = 10M, 
                                       companyid = 7 
                                   };
        xs.Serialize(sw, a);
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlElement("Company")]
    public string Company { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Amount")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public int companyid { get; set; }
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Company>Company Name</Company>
  <Amount>10</Amount>
</MyClass>
```

If you need this code to inspect the class to determine which properties to exclude based on an `XmlElementAttribute` not being present, then you can modify the above code to use reflection to enumerate the properties of the object. For every property that does not have an `XmlElementAttribute`, add an item to the `overrides` instance.

For example:

```
void Main()
{
    //Serialize, but ignore properties that do not have XmlElementAttribute
    var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
    var attributes = new XmlAttributes();
    attributes.XmlIgnore = true;
    foreach(var prop in typeof(MyClass).GetProperties())
    {
        var attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlElementAttribute));
        if(attrs.Count() == 0)
            overrides.Add(prop.DeclaringType, prop.Name, attributes);
    }

    using(var sw = new StringWriter()) {
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass), overrides);
        var a = new MyClass() { 
                                Company = "Company Name", 
                                Amount = 10M, 
                                companyid = 7,
                                blah = "123" };
        xs.Serialize(sw, a);
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlElement("Company")]
    public string Company { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Amount")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public int companyid { get; set; }

    public string blah { get; set; }
}
```