# rename property in xml schema class when serializing

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-serialization

I have an auto generated c# class file from an xml schema using the xsd generator tool.

There is a property in this class that i need to rename from "Balance" to "balance" when the xml file gets created.

As this is a generated class i need to update the created xml object on the fly before seralizing so cant just add an atrribute over the class property with the expected name.

I have accomplished the task of ignoring certain properties by using the XmlAttributes class so am sure there is something i could do along same lines for this

Can anyone point me in the direction of how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: `[XmlElement("balance")]` tag on the element?

Comment: It's a generated class so I can't add that , needs to be manipulated just before I serialize the object

Comment: Is the idea that you need to deserialize from XML that has `<Balance>` and serialize to XML that has `<balance>`?

Comment: no i im not doing any de-serliazing, am creating a new instance of the generated xsd class and populating it from a txt file thats passed in to the app - then just before im serialzing it out to an xml file i perform one ot two tasks to ignore attributes which get created automatically and now i need to rename an attribute/property before finishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to resolve my issue by using the following:

```
var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();  

overrides.Add(typeof(MyGeneratedCustomType), "Balance", new XmlAttributes { XmlAttribute = new XmlAttributeAttribute("balance") });

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(xmlFile.GetType(), overrides);
```

MyGeneratedCustomType is a type that appears in the generated xsd class which holds the property i needed to rename.   Its an elegant solution as there is very minimal code required.

Comment: Learned something new here.  Cool.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to deserialize from XML like this:

```
<root>
  <Balance />
</root>
```

and then serialize to XML like this:

```
<root>
  <balance />
</root>
```

You have two options here:

1. You could just create a second class that mirrors your auto-generated class in every way except for having `[XmlElement("balance")]` on the Balance property in the mirrored class.  If the generated class is `XsdGenerated` and the mirrored class is `CustomClass`, create a constructor or override the `=`s operator to be able to populate the `CustomClass` with all the fields from `XsdGenerated`.  When you serialize `CustomClass`, you should get the desired result.  I think this is the preferable option.
2. Implement `IXmlSerializable` on `XsdGenerated`.  Call `base()` in the `ReadXml` method, and just have the `WriteXml` method create the `balance` tag in lower case.  Note that this option is probably more challenging to write/maintain and would limit your ability to serialize and deserialize  - it'd be a one way operation, unless you created an even more complex mechanism to set whether `ReadXml()` and `WriteXml()` should treat `balance` with an upper or lower case b.

Comment: Thanks Dan, i prefer option 1 as a resolution, in the end i managed to find another way which i have just posted.

Comment: Also - this was a good starting point to my issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377414/excluding-some-properties-during-serialization-without-changing-the-original-cla