# How to auto-ignore all properties with no corresponding constructor parameter when serializing

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net, deserialization

Is there some non-attribute-based method of ignoring all properties that don't have a corresponding constructor parameter when serializing?  For example, when serializing this class, property `Combo` should be ignored.  A round-trip serialization/deserialization of an instance of `MyClass` doesn't require `Combo` to be serialized.  Ideally I could use some out-of-the-box setting.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(int myInt, string myString)
    {
        this.MyInt = myInt;
        this.MyString = myString;
    }

    public int MyInt { get; }

    public string MyString { get; }

    public string Combo => this.MyInt + this.MyString;
}
```

Comment: if parameters name in the constructor are the same as attributes names, I think that reflection may help you to get the list of properties that should be serialized. Then you can use this simple to create the non-attribute-based method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377414/excluding-some-properties-during-serialization-without-changing-the-original-cla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a [custom `IContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm):

```
public class ConstructorPropertiesOnlyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    readonly bool serializeAllWritableProperties;

    public ConstructorPropertiesOnlyContractResolver(bool serializeAllWritableProperties)
        : base()
    {
        this.serializeAllWritableProperties = serializeAllWritableProperties;
    }

    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);

        if (contract.CreatorParameters.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var property in contract.Properties)
            {
                if (contract.CreatorParameters.GetClosestMatchProperty(property.PropertyName) == null)
                {
                    if (!serializeAllWritableProperties || !property.Writable)
                        property.Readable = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return contract;
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new ConstructorPropertiesOnlyContractResolver(false) };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass, Formatting.Indented, settings );
```

Pass `true` for `serializeAllWritableProperties` if you also want to serialize read/write properties that are not included in the constructor parameter list, e.g. `AnUnrelatedReadWriteProperty` in:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(int myInt, string myString)
    {
        this.MyInt = myInt;
        this.MyString = myString;
    }

    public int MyInt { get; private set; }

    public string MyString { get; private set; }

    public string Combo { get { return this.MyInt + this.MyString; } }

    public string AnUnrelatedReadWriteProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Note you may want to [cache your contract resolver for best performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557737/does-json-net-cache-types-serialization-information).

Comment: wow, awsome answer!  thanks so much for taking the time to write this up.