# C# - XmlIgnore doesn't work with override or new modifier

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

```
[TestFixture]
public class XmlIgnoreWithNewModifierTest
{
    public class Parent
    {
        public int Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child : Parent
    {
        [XmlIgnore]
        public new int Name
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Child));
        var stream = new MemoryStream();

        // Throws
        serializer.Serialize(stream, new Child());
    }
}
```

The last line of code would throw `InvalidOperationException` with an inner `NotImplementedException`. Making `Parent.Name` virtual and `Child.Name` override doesn't help.

I wonder if it is possible to make XmlIgnore only work on `Child.Name` but not `Parent.Name`?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this answer :
[Excluding some properties during serialization without changing the original class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377414/excluding-some-properties-during-serialization-without-changing-the-original-cla)

You should use :

```
XmlAttributes attributes = new XmlAttributes { XmlIgnore = true };
XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
overrides.Add(typeof(Parent), "Name", attributes);

XmlSerializer serialize = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Child), overrides);
```